# How to make columns not dependent on each other with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, jinja2

There is a menu on the left with the effect of the accordion, on the right content is formed with a jinja. I need to do so that the height of the menu and the contents do not depend on each other.
as here: [click](https://www.ebay.com/rpp/electronics-en)

HTML:

```
<!-- menu -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="header-tabs">Brands</h1>
      <div class="tab">
        {% for brand in brands %}
          <button value="{{ brand.id }}">{{ brand.brand_name }
          </button>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 <!-- content -->
{% for sm in smartphones %}
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img class="photo-phone" height="150" width="150" src="{{ sm.photo.url }}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h3 class="header-phone">{{ sm.brand }} {{ sm.model }}</h3>
      <p descr-phone>{{ sm.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4 class="price">{{ sm.price }}$</h4>
      <input type="button" class="button-buy" value="Buy">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @WebDevBooster 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to achieve that is by nesting. Nesting must always be done using row-column pairs i.e. never nest a column directly inside another column.

So, in your case, you'd first create a column with the class `col-md-9` then put a `.row` inside that column and then put all your content columns inside that newly created row.

Note that inside this newly created row you now have a total of 12 column units to work with.

Click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page for testing:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- menu -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1 class="header-tabs">Brands:</h1>
                <div class="tab">
<!--                    {% for brand in brands %}-->
                    <button value="{{ brand.id }}">
<!--                    {{ brand.brand_name }-->
                       Brand Name
                    </button>
<!--                    {% endfor %}-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- content -->
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <!--        {% for sm in smartphones %}-->
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <!--            <img class="photo-phone" height="150" width="150" src="{{ sm.photo.url }}">-->
                    <img class="photo-phone img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="header-phone">
                        <!--            {{ sm.brand }} {{ sm.model }}-->
                        Brand Model
                    </h3>
                    <p descr-phone>
                        <!--            {{ sm.description }}-->
                        Description
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <h4 class="price">
                        <!--            {{ sm.price }}$-->
                        $1,000
                    </h4>
                    <input type="button" class="button-buy" value="Buy">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <!--            <img class="photo-phone" height="150" width="150" src="{{ sm.photo.url }}">-->
                    <img class="photo-phone img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="header-phone">
                        <!--            {{ sm.brand }} {{ sm.model }}-->
                        Brand Model
                    </h3>
                    <p descr-phone>
                        <!--            {{ sm.description }}-->
                        Description
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <h4 class="price">
                        <!--            {{ sm.price }}$-->
                        $1,000
                    </h4>
                    <input type="button" class="button-buy" value="Buy">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <!--            <img class="photo-phone" height="150" width="150" src="{{ sm.photo.url }}">-->
                    <img class="photo-phone img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="header-phone">
                        <!--            {{ sm.brand }} {{ sm.model }}-->
                        Brand Model
                    </h3>
                    <p descr-phone>
                        <!--            {{ sm.description }}-->
                        Description
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <h4 class="price">
                        <!--            {{ sm.price }}$-->
                        $1,000
                    </h4>
                    <input type="button" class="button-buy" value="Buy">
                </div>
                <!--        {% endfor %}-->
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Also note the use of the spacing class `mb-3` (margin-bottom 3 units).

The `img-fluid` class makes the images responsive.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting